# Using a file's contents in a curl command connecting to a Flask API

Tags: python, flask, curl

Here's my intent:  I need  to use curl to connect to my Python application's Flask API, and upload the contents of a text file to be used by the Python application.  However, I cannot seem to both complete the connection and upload the data.

Based upon lots of otherwise-fruitless searching, I am using the following command-line:

`curl -X POST -i -F 'input_txt=@single_file.txt' http://myhost:5000/api_tst01/`

However, that gives me a key error on the server side:

```
  File "U:\home\testapp\app.py", line 303, in api_tst01
    print(request.form["input_txt"])
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\users\<me>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures\structures.py", line 192, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

My server-side code is the following:

```
@app.route('/api_tst01/', methods=['POST'])
def api_tst01():
    print(request.form["input_txt"])
```

At this point, I figure that if I can print it, I can otherwise access/use it to parse through for  the relevant data.  Clearly *something* is getting through, but how can I get to it?  The file itself contains some XML data, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a simple form value, like this:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/api_tst01 -F input_txt='hello world'
```

The request looks like (you can see this using the `--trace-ascii <filename>` option to `curl`):

```
POST /api_tst01 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 147
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------
----f74b8d8f0b3df63b

--------------------------f74b8d8f0b3df63b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input_txt"

foo
--------------------------f74b8d8f0b3df63b--
```

On the other hand, when reading data from a file, like this:

```
echo hello world > input.txt
curl http://localhost:5000/api_tst01 -F input_txt=@input.txt
```

We get:

```
POST /api_tst01 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 204
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------
----cb4e6a25eda23951

--------------------------cb4e6a25eda23951
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input_txt"; filename="input.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

hello world.
--------------------------cb4e6a25eda23951--
```

Note in particular the `Content-disposition` line, which includes a `filename=` attribute in the second example.

This causes Flask to place the received data into your application's `files` attribute, rather than the `form` attribute. We can see the different if we write a simple server like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api_tst01', methods=['POST'])
def api_tst01():
    print('files:', request.files)
    print('form:', request.form)
    return "Thanks"
```

When we make the first request (with `-F input_txt='hello world'`), we see:

```
files: ImmutableMultiDict([])
form: ImmutableMultiDict([('input_txt', 'hello world')])
```

But when we make the second request (with `-F input_txt=@input.txt`), we see:

```
files: ImmutableMultiDict([('input_txt', <FileStorage: 'input.txt' ('text/plain')>)])
form: ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

So you probably want to write your code to handle both situations:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api_tst01', methods=['POST'])
def api_tst01():
    if 'input_txt' in request.form:
        data = request.form['input_txt']
    elif 'input_txt' in request.files:
        data = request.files['input_txt'].read()

    print('received:', data)
    return "Thanks"
```

The above works, but note that the received data is slightly different for `request.forms` vs `request.files` (in the first case it's a unicode string; in the second case it's a byte string and probably includes a trailing newline) .

Comment: Ah, this puts the pieces together - thanks!  I now have data I can use as input.  Now I can't get it to be recognized as valid XML, but that's another story for another issue.  Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like request.files['input_txt'].read().decode("utf8") was what I needed.

Comment: If this answered your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks!